# Как вывести часть строки

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select e.EventName from event e
```

есть строка `Points [{X}] (Including OT)` в table ,
хочу вывесть эту строку так => Points (Including OT)
как это сделать?

я длжен вывести строку без {X}
например:

```
Total{x} => должен вывести Total
TotalToTal{x} => должен вывести TotalToTal
```

Comment: Ненадо этого делать на SQL, но если очень хочется - регулярные выражения гуглите

Comment: исправил можешь посмотреть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT CASE WHEN event_name LIKE '%{%}%'
            THEN LEFT(event_name, CHARINDEX('{', event_name) - 1) 
               + SUBSTRING(event_name, CHARINDEX('}', event_name) + 1, LEN(event_name))
            ELSE event_name
            END event_name
FROM event
```